# jquery: Append, Prepend, Html event

Tags: jquery, append

I need to catch $.append() method, something like this

```
$('div').bind('append', function(){
    /* code here */
});
```

or

```
$('div').bind('html', function(){
    /* code here */
});
```

How i can get this?

Comment: Have you got any more context?

Comment: Catch it in the function that appends the code

Comment: No. I need to replace all select elements at my website. But there is some append() methods in my code. 
I decide to catch all this methods and update fake-select in real time to avoid some bugs can probably be

Comment: Johan, may be there are some other solutions?

Comment: @КонстантинДаруткин I've added a solution with one common custom event. I think that's the closest you'll get to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On all the places where you append stuff, trigger a custom event:

```
$('#bar').append('...');
$.event.trigger('customappend');
```

... and trigger it on all places where you append code:

```
$('#foo').append('...');
$.event.trigger('customappend');
```

Listen for it in one place:

```
$(document).on('customappend', function(){
    /* code here */
});
```

---

Solution #2 (using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver)):

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log('target mutated');
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();

$(document).click(function(){
    $('#id').append('.');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VTmk5/1/

Comment: Thanks. But i need to look through all my code. If it is, i won't need this feature. I need some universal solution

Comment: @КонстантинДаруткин What browsers are you supporting?

Comment: All. Only one solution i see - edit jquery core. But it is an extreme case @Johan

Comment: @КонстантинДаруткин Try my update. Worked for me in Chrome and FF.